# jquery / javascript - Simple split() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
if ($(".productpage .description").html() != null) {

    var textToHide = $('.productpage .description').html().split('<br class="breakHere">')[1];
    var visibleText = $('.productpage .description').html().split('<br class="breakHere">')[0]; 
}
```

Works great in Firefox, but in IE and Chrome textToHide and visibleText are undefined. Did I miss something? Thanks

Comment: Can you paste a sample html as well. What exactly are you trying to do, cause it feels like there could be a better way to approach this as well...

Comment: You should cache the results from your selector.  `$('.productpage .description')` won't be particularly fast, especially in IE 7 and IE 6.  Store the result in a variable you can reuse and performance will increase.

Comment: and he should cache the results of `.html().split()` too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View your `$('.productpage .description').html()`, you may be getting `<br />`

Comment: Found the problem:

For some reason IE changed it to

<BR class=breakHere>

Chrome was just a cache issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()` against HTML isn't a good idea IMHO - it's too brittle, and is likely to suffer the same problems as using Regexp's against HTML.

Assuming that the elements you're trying to split are all siblings with the `<br>` element, try this:

```
var $el = $('.productionpage .description'); // find the element
var $br = $('br.breakHere', $el);            // find the BR inside it

var $vis = $br.prevAll();             // contains everything before the break
var $hide = $br.nextAll();            // contains everything after the break
```

Note that this will give you jQuery objects containing those elements, not the HTML text of them.